# Schmitt trigger oscillators interfere with eachother (74HC14)

Tags: oscillator, schmitt-trigger

[image: circuit]

I am using a single 74HC14 (hex schmitt trigger) to implement three oscillators. I now have a test build ready and encounter problems. See schematic, it shows component values. Also

- proper 5V power supply
- 2u2 electrolytic bypass near chip
- 100n ceramic disc bypass next to chip
- unused schmitt triggers' inputs are on ground or vcc
- outputs connected to inverting opamp amplifiers, each their own opamp with 100k and 500nF in series to the inverting input (the C is for DC blocking)

The problem is: each of the three oscillators interfere with the other ones, changing their frequency. E.g. if oscillator 1 is set at 50 Hz, turning up 2 or 3 will cause 1 to go up in frequency (wild changes, think +50%)

I'd think the schmitt triggers are not loaded very high (resistances are all >100k, problems occur with the potmeters at around 200k already) so surely I'm not pushing it in terms of sink/source current.

Comment: Try a ceramic decoupling capacitor.

Comment: To be placed where?

Comment: How much cross-coupling is acceptable?... it is uavoidable, especially when all three are in the same chip.

Comment: How much does the frequency change? Provide numbers for "turning up 2 or 3" and "cause 1 to go up".

Comment: I think the 50 Hz jumped to like 70 Hz. They're not just small fluctuations.

Comment: This does not make sense if your input power is good... Are there resets etc you need to check? Do you have a scope to check your vcc line?

Comment: So normally if you just post a photo of your breadboard you get yelled at for no schematic.  Could you post a photo of your breadboard so we can see what you mean when you say the 100nF cap is "close to" the chip?  I would expect a bit of cross-coupling between oscillators, but not that much unless your power to the chip is horrible.  I second @MadHatter's recommendation to look at the power line -- look at it right across the power and ground pins on the chip.

Comment: Also, how are you measuring frequency?