# Solar-powered 74HC14 LED flasher: oscillators interfere

Tags: low-power, schmitt-trigger, blink

I am building a "nocturnal solar engine" with two LEDs flashing independently, following the description at the old [Solarbotics](http://solarbotics.net/library/circuits/bot_pummer.html) website. I am essentially rebuilding the same circuit. The schematic and a photo of my breadboard is below.

I am using two different resistors for R3 and R5 to get a nicely asynchronous blink from the two LEDs. What I am experiencing, however, is that when the two flashes get close to each other (around 0.1 sec), they actually happen in sync, and the two oscillators' phases keep restarting from this shared moment. After a while, the independent flashing even stops, and I am left with two LEDs flashing completely in sync.

Diagnostics so far: When the solar panel is off and the circuit on the right is working, I am measuring 1.99V in the IC's circuit (the bottom power line on my breadboard). I have tried various combinations of R3/R5 resistors, different types of LEDs, and 10uF instead of 22uF for C4/C6, but the two oscillators always end up in sync.

You can watch a video of the LEDs syncing up via this Dropbox [shared link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hcqprgucyqajx1/pummer-sync.mov?dl=0). To clarify, here's a table with each flash's timestamps (jotted down while watching the video frame by frame). Yellow's interval fluctuates but seems to be around 1.90 sec. However, when the "synchronized" flash occurs (the two highlights), it flashes over 100msec too early. It should flash later, not in sync with Red.

[image: LED flash timestamps]

A similar problem was reported in [Q406793](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/406793/schmitt-trigger-oscillators-interfere-with-eachother-74hc14), but that question has not been resolved.

[image: 74HC14 pummer schematic]
[image: 74HC14 pummer breadboard]

Comment: Probably a combination of no current limiting on your LEDs, a supply voltage that is (just) below the bottom operational limit for the 74HC14 and a lack of decoupling. Try the right hand side with a proper bench supply and see if it works any better.

Comment: Will do and report back! I did try current limiting on the LEDs with a 1k resistor, but it didn't make a difference. What would decoupling mean in this circuit?

Comment: Same as it did in the other answer you linked to, a 0.1uF capacitor across the supply pins as close as possible to the HC14.

Comment: I watched the video - I don't see the LEDs "syncing up". The yellow LED is consistently blinking faster than the red. The fact that they occasionally overlap and blink at the same time is expected. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The Rs are not exact multiples of each other. I don't think the two LEDs should regularly blink at exactly the same time. Also, after a while, the separate frequencies simply disappear and the two LEDs blink completely in tandem.

Comment: Then post a video showing them doing so. The one you've shared shows them working exactly the way I'd expect them to work.

Comment: @Finbarr added table with timing of flashes extracted from the video. I explain where the sync-up happens: Yellow flashes too early when its flash would otherwise be close to, but after, Red's flash. I disagree that this is how I expect them to work. I expect Red's and Yellow's flashes to be independent.

Comment: I added the 0.1uF capacitor to decouple, and it eliminated the fully degenerate state where the two LEDs end up completely in sync. Also, now it takes more cycles before Yellow syncs up with Red. I.e., the different flashes now need to be less then 0.140msec close, but the sync-up ultimately still happens.

Comment: Well, I suppose when one HC14 buffer switches low there's a spike in current to charge the large cap, and this current could couple to the other buffer (via a sag in the the local VCC or ground bounce inside the IC) which could affect the switching threshold of the other buffer. So, a decoupling cap will help - go bigger then 0.1uF, make it 22uF and put it directly to the HC14 power pin.

Comment: I'd agree, the red turning on probably pulls the supply down a little and affects the switching levels causing the yellow to flash early. You're running right at the bottom of the recommended supply range as it is and breadboard isn't going to provide as reliable a connection as proper soldered joints.